# How to create an Octave function for evaluating sum of odd numbers in the vector only?

Tags: matlab, octave

I created a function file on Octave like this,

```
function y = sum_odd(n)
       if rem(n,2) ==1
         sum_odd = sum(n)
       endif
    endfunction
```

and I want to make the function evaluate the sum of odd numbers in every vectors.
But when I tried sum_odd([1 2 3]), it didn't calculate for me.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: You are clearly just learning matlab and are coming from a different language - there are basic syntax issues here: just use `end` rather than `endif` or `endfunction`; you are assigning to the function name `sum_odd` rather than the return variable `y`; in matlab the function is `mod` not `rem`.  Furthermore this is also clearly a tutorial question you are answering, so it won't really help you if we just give you the answer.  There is lots of good online documentation for matlab, try "Indexing with Logical Values" [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html)

Comment: @EuanSmith I'm sorry to misunderstand you. I meant Octave GUI not Matlab. The languages are similar.

Comment: Ah, OK. However the indexing with logical values is still the reference you need - this is the same in both.

Comment: @EuanSmith: `mod` and `rem` both exist in MATLAB and don’t do the same thing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo indeed.  I checked that out already.  However the `endif` is not in matlab, and assigning to `sum_odd` was incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html):

```
function y = sum_odd(n)
    y = sum(n(rem(n,2)==1))
end
```

- `rem([1 2 3],2)==1)` returns logical array: `[1 0 1]`.
- `n(logical([1 0 1])) returns`[1 3]`.
- `sum(n(rem([1 2 3], 2) == 1))` returns sum of `[1 3]`.